# How to put Calendar Icon to Datepicker in right side

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project, In my project I am trying to put the calendar icon on the right

Side for Datepicker. Here I am using Fontawesome icons. But It is showing some error please

help me to solve this.

This is App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      startDate: ''
    }
  }

  handleChange = date => {
    this.setState({
      startDate: date
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <DatePicker
      placeholderText={'Select date'}
        selected={this.state.startDate}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        <i class="far fa-calendar"></i>
      />
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Comment: You can use the react-datepicker `customInput` prop to overwrite the input element it renders.

Answer (score 3):

Creating your own input in react-datepicker is possible using [customInput](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-custom-input) option.

You can take a look at this component: [DatePickerComponent](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-hooks-jzj05?file=/src/DatePickerComponent.js). Here I used [styled-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components) library but you can achieve similar result using simple CSS.

Comment: How I can get the selected date at parent component?

Comment: You can move selectedDate state to the parent component and pass it in props to a child component.

Comment: Seems like alot of code just to add an icon. I would assume there is a better way.